# Simple question on associativity and commutativity in a group

Tags: group-theory

This seems to me to be a rather silly question, but I want to be sure that I'm getting it right.

Say that I have a group $G$, and I consider the element $a \in G$ and specifically the element $a^5$. It is certainly the case that
$$a^5 = a^3 a^2.$$
Is the justification for this step associativitiy in the group? Or am I using the fact that any element of a group commutes with powers of itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To clarify things, you should first think about this question: what do $a^3$ and $a^5$ mean?

You may want to define them recursively: $a^n$ is by definition $a^{n - 1}\cdot a$. This would lead to the following definition: $$a^3 = (a\cdot a)\cdot a.$$

But why not $a^3 = a \cdot (a \cdot a)$, which looks equally good as a definition?

Things get worse for $a^5$: it could be $((((a \cdot a)\cdot a)\cdot a)\cdot a)$, or $(a\cdot(a\cdot(a\cdot(a\cdot a))))$, or $(a \cdot a) \cdot ((a \cdot a) \cdot a)$, or many many other possibilities.

---

The reason that we don't have to deal with this complication is exactly **associativity**.

By the associativity axiom, all the above definitions should give the same element, hence justifying the notations $a^3$ and $a^5$, i.e. we can put parentheses anywhere in the defining formula.

And after that, it becomes trivial to see that $a^5 = a^3 \cdot a^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Associativity is what is required here. Without associativity, this doesn't work. Let's say the operation is subtraction on the integers, which is not associative. We compute
$$1^5 = -3$$
$$1^3 = -1$$
$$1^2 = 0$$
So
$$1^31^2 = -1\neq 1^5$$
If you want to single out associativity we can use $xy = 2|x-y|$, since this operation is commutative. Then we get
$$1^5 = 2$$
$$1^3 = 2$$
$$1^2 = 0$$
$$1^31^2 = 4\neq 1^5$$

Answer (score 1):

If we define $a^{n+1}=a^n\cdot a$, then the claim is
$$(((a\cdot a)\cdot a)\cdot a)\cdot a = ((a\cdot a)\cdot 
a)\cdot(a\cdot a)$$
and this is associativity applied to $(a\cdot a)\cdot 
a, a, a$.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider the following simple example of a magma to see that being accotiativity is vital for your specific conclusion:

```
+|a b 
-----
a|b b  
b|b a
```

Comment: Please elaborate, as can only understand $a+a=b, a+b=b,  b+a=b, b+b=a$. So, $a+(a+a)=a+b=b, $$a+(a+b) =a+b=b,$$  a+(b+a)=a+b=b, $$a+(b+b)=a+a=b$, but $(a+a)+a=b+a=b, $$ (a+a)+b=b+b=a, $$(a+b)+a=b+a=b, (a+b)+b=b+b=a$. Also, there is no identity, as $a+a=b$, which for $a$ to be an identity should have been $a+a=a$.